# How to manipulate Compressed Sparse Row Format (CSR) matrix

Tags: matrix, fortran, sparse-matrix

I have some NxN symmetric matrix A, and I want to extract the elements of this matrix and construct it with several matrices. For example, 
A_1 = A(1:10,1:10), A_2 = A(11:N, 11:N), A_3 =(1:10,11:N).

In the case of MATLAB, the sparse matrix can also be written as above. However, in my Fortran code, it can not be written as above because matrix A is stored in CSR format. Moreover, all matrices have to be saved in CSR format. What should I do in this case?

Question: Is there any library like MATLAB sparse function that makes it easy to handle sparse matrices available in Fortran?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry to make you ambiguous. I did not mean to write code. 
1. What does decompress CSR mean?
2. What I wanted to ask is whether there is a library like MATLAB sparse function that makes it easy to handle sparse matrices available in Fortran.
Thank you for your comment.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_row_.28CSR.2C_CRS_or_Yale_format.29